# Sum of numeric values and +/- signs as string algorithm

Tags: python

So I have this string:

```
s = 'one+one-two-one+two'
```

And I need to calculate the sum of this.

Tis is what I have try:

```
s = 'one+one-two-one+two'
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
add = s.split('+')
result = 0
for i in range(len(add)):
    val = d.get(add[i], None)
    if val:
        result += val
    else:
        sub = add[i].split('-')
        for j in range(len(sub)):
            if j > 0:
                result -= d[sub[j]]
            else:
                result += d[sub[j]]
print(result)
```

In case `'one+one-two-one+two'` to `'one+-one-two-one+two'` my way not works well.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `eval(s.replace('one', '1').replace('two', '2'))`

Comment: What are you having trouble with/Do you have a specific question? Are you just looking for a code review? There's https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EugeneSh. Or `for word, num in d.items(): s = s.replace(word, str(num)); eval(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.split()` to split it using both `+` and `-`. Then in the loop you can add or subtract depending on which delimiter is before each number.

```
import re

s = 'one+one-two-one+two'
d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

parsed = re.split(r'([-+])', s)
total = d.get(parsed[0])
    
for i in range(1, len(parsed), 2):
    op = parsed[i]
    num = d.get(parsed[i+1])
    if op == '+':
        total += num
    else:
        total -= num

print(total)
```

Putting the regexp in a capture group makes `re.split()` include the delimters in the list of results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive approach:

```
def calc(s,sign=1):
    if s.startswith('+'):   return calc(s[1:], sign)
    if s.startswith('-'):   return calc(s[1:],-sign)
    if s.startswith('one'): return sign * 1 + calc(s[3:])
    if s.startswith('two'): return sign * 2 + calc(s[3:])
    return 0
```

output:

```
print(calc('one+one-two-one+two')) # 1

print(calc('one+-one-two-one+two')) # -1
```